# Violation of Title Deed Covenants

Tags: england-and-wales, property

Title deeds in England often stipulate a list of restrictions and obligations. I am unclear though who can enforce them and how. My current title prevents me interfering with people trying to attend a nearby church. Previous ones prevented me storing a boat on my drive or participating in immoral acts. Others prevented me from operating a tannery. My question is — what happens if I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A person with [standing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_(law)) can sue to enforce them

In the UK, standing is interpreted broadly as anyone with an interest in the matter who suffers or might suffer detriment from your breach.